# Why Dataflow step is waiting for previous steps

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I created a beam pipeline that I am running on dataflow.
The pipeline contains 4 steps:

1. read file contents
2. convert file contents to json
3. transform the json entries
4. save transformed json entries into GCS

The probleme is that steps 3 and 4 are blocked waiting for steps 1 and 2 to finish reading all files.. Is there an explanation why the latest steps don't just handle each file data on the flow ?

Answer (score 0):

Batch Dataflow pipelines run in stages, where each stage waits for its inputs before starting.  See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization for information on how Dataflow divides up pipelines into stages.